# I have to show three cards in a row, but for some reason I'm getting cards stacked over each other

Tags: javascript, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, react-native, react-redux

[Showing Card Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD1Vb.png)

[Creating Card Component](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o4eIB.png)

[Result- Images are on top of each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVOOv.png)

Comment: please post code snippets not screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

In this image https://i.stack.imgur.com/aD1Vb.png on line 21, I see that you have missed "-", it should be "col-md-4". And your loop should start from the column like this.

```
{products.map(item => (
  <div className="col-md-4">
  // Other codes here
  </div>
))}
```